# How do I pass BufferedImage to Filedialog to save in Java?

Tags: java, awtrobot, filedialog

I'm a Java beginner. I'm building a screenshot application, wherein you press <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> and it captures the screen. I want this screen image to be saved with the help of a `Filedialog` or `JFileChooser`. I am not sure how to pass the `BufferedImage` to the `Filedialog` box. In my code I have just hard coded the saving location.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SeeEyeEye {
public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame aWindow = new JFrame("SeeEyeEye");
aWindow.setBounds(100, 310, 210, 110);
aWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 JTextField typingArea = new JTextField(20);
 typingArea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {


        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
           displayInfo(e, "KEY TYPED: "); }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
           displayInfo(e, "KEY PRESSED: "); }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
           displayInfo(e, "KEY RELEASED: "); }


  protected void displayInfo(KeyEvent e, String s) {
    String keyString;

      int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
      if(keyCode==154) {  
                 try {

                         Robot robot = new Robot();
                          // Capture the screen shot of the area of the screen defined by the rectangle
                           BufferedImage bi=robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,25,1366,744));
                           ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("C://Users//Rao//Desktop//s.png"));
                }

                     catch (AWTException e1) {
                         e1.printStackTrace(); }
                     catch (IOException e1) {
                         e1.printStackTrace(); }

               }
      else { System.out.println("try again");}
      keyString = "key code = " + keyCode + " (" + KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode) + ")";
  System.out.println(keyString);

    }

});
aWindow.add(typingArea);
aWindow.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: Use the FileDialog or JFileChooser to get the path/name of the file, and use that File to save the Image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a FileDialog or JFileChooser to get the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) (name and path) the user selects. Then use this File to save the image using [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html):

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if ( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ){
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    ImageIO.write(image, 'jpg', file);//assuming you want a jpg, and BufferedImage variable name is image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass the '`Buffered Image`' to the file.

`FileDialog` is to ask the user where to store the file, and once the user selects the location and file name, you write the 'Buffered Image' to that file and save it.